# pyqt with native python thread qpixmap and parent error

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm using python native thread with pyqt default thread. When I want show qmessagebox in native thread, my program is crashed.
Here is my code:

```
.........
self.serverSoc.listen(5)
self.status="Server listening on %s:%s" % serveraddr
self.serverStatus = 1
thread.start_new_thread(self.listenClients, ())

def listenClients(self):
    while 1:
        clientsoc, clientaddr = self.serverSoc.accept()
        print("Client connected from %s:%s" % clientaddr)
        data = clientsoc.recv(self.buffsize)
        if data.startswith('%sendchatrequest%'):
            try:
                requestuser = data.rsplit(':', 1)[1]
                msg = "%s wanted to chat with you. Do you accept this?" %requestuser

                reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Chat Request',
                                                   msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
```

and I got this error:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
X Error: BadImplementation (server does not implement operation) 17
Major opcode: 20 (X_GetProperty)
Resource id:  0x0
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python2.7: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
```

how can I fix it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Qt requires that all GUI operations are done in the main thread.

Why not use a [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) instead which nicely integrates into Qt's mainloop instead of requiring a thread?